# Running different makefiles in windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, makefile, thrift

I've downloaded Apache Thrift and have created a thrift file that nicely generates code (I'm using csharp). I've now got to the stage of including Thrift in my Visual Studio project (I'm using 2013 version) and am stuck on how to do this.

Thrift includes all the source files I need but just copying them to Visual Studio creates a load of errors. I noticed that there are several makefiles that come with the source: There's a Makefile.am and a Makefile.in. I tried running:

```
nmake -f Makefile.am
nmake -f Makefile.in
```

but i keep getting syntax errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here are the syntax errors:

```
 Makefile.am(73) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing
Stop.
```

and:

```
Makefile.in(16) : fatal error U1035: syntax error : expected ':' or '=' separator
Stop.
```

Comment: Please post the syntax errors and the associated snippets from your make file. Hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: The help I need is what to do with all the different types of makefiles. As you can see the errors are just basic syntax one's. As I understand it you need a makefile.win before you can run nmake so how do i get a makefile.win from a makefile.in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see the errors are just basic syntax one's.

Still a good idea to post the source **and** the error messages. We don't like guesswork, because it is highly inefficient. And you want quick help, don't you?

> The help I need is what to do with all the different types of makefiles.

First, I'm not sure why you need a makefile at all. You could easily achieve he same result by calling Thrift in the prebuild step. I do that via batch files, which gives me enough control over the process. But, yes, you could of course also call `nmake -f makefile` here, but note there is **no extension** after `makefile`.

In a nutshell and without spending too much time on details, the `makefile.am` and `makefile.in` are typically GNU automake files. Roughly, during `bootstrap.sh && configure` these `makefile.am` files are converted into `makefile.in` files and finally into `makefile` files, which then are to be consumed by `make` or  equivalent tools.

But honestly, on Windows platforms, GNU automake is something that I would consider the option of last resort - if there is *any other option* available, choose that one.

Last not least, the tutorial, library and test *.csproj files show at least one way how to integrate Thrift in the prebuild step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've now managed to get a project working by just copying the thrift csharp source files into the application project and then adding the required references. The makefiles came with the download and as I understand it they create a .dll from the source files? Wich would be easier to use than copy pase!

Comment: The Assembly can be created using [/lib/csharp/src/Thrift.csproj](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/csharp/src/Thrift.csproj). You may also copy the sources into your application, there's nothing wrong with that (except for the duplicated code in your assemblies, of course). The makefiles are there to build the Thrift compiler and libraries on *nix platforms. On Windows, you can safely ignore them, because for almost everything you need with C# there is some kind of Visual Studio project file available.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.